# Speed up android app development with BlueStacks App Player on Mac

Tags: android, eclipse, macos, bluestacks

I installed the BlueStacks App Player on my Mac (Version: Version 0.3.6), because the android emulator is very slow. My current testing process is as follows:

1. Export project in Eclipse as `.apk`
2. Move `.apk` in Dropbox
3. Open Dropbox in BlueStacks App Player
4. Open the `.apk` and install it
5. Test it

As you can see, it takes a lot of time to test apps. Is it possible to speed up this process? Like to run directly from eclipse the application in the BlueStacks App Player?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can use [Intel HAXM](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager) but GenyMotion is much faster than any other emulator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is no faster android emulator which can be integrated into eclipse and/or accessed via adb then

http://www.genymotion.com/

Comment: first I want to say that I love genymotion and I use it everyday. But there's another slightly unstable, a bit experimental, that when it works I feel it works even faster than Genymotion, Android L preview emulator. Because the emulator runs on a x86 ART (Android runtime), the thing is FAST! Give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to run Android Emulator faster. 
1. First create an Intel x86 Atom System emulator in your AVD.
2. In order to run this emulator fast, in your SDK manager download the Intel x86 emulator Accelerator (Haxm installer), inside your extras folder you will find installation files for it and just install it. However please note that HAXM might not be supported by every computer. You can check out intel website about Haxm drivers. Once you get your emulator running with hardware acceleration. You emulator will be as fast as iOS Simulator.